# Find All Classes with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I want to know how I can get element by class name where every class partially same like

class = "cursor earn_pages_button profile_view_img_xxxx" where xxxx is undefined

I just want to get all images from this class name profile_view_img_xxxx

some where it is profile_view_img_32487 or profile_view_img_86732 or profile_view_img_3278324

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,"cursor earn_pages_button profile_view_img_")]").
```

It will match all classes with that text. Just try to iterate through it using a for-loop.

Comment: Should be `driver.find_elements...`

Comment: but you have `find_element` instead of `find_elements` which will not return all elements.